# changing vector drawable color

Tags: android, vector, drawable

I converted the png file to SVG and got it from http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ to find the vector path information.

I have been trying to support from api level 21 to get the right resolution for all screen sizes by using vector drawables. (My app`s minSdk is 21)

The problem is that the text is white and the background color is transparent, but I am trying to change it using the fillColor attribute or strokeColor, but somehow not working well.

how do I achieve this? I want text`s color is white and other background is transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="386.000000dp"
android:height="149.000000dp"
android:viewportWidth="386.000000"
android:viewportHeight="149.000000"
>

<group
    android:translateY="149.000000"
    android:scaleX="0.100000"
    android:scaleY="-0.100000"
    >
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="3"
        android:pathData="M0 745 l0 -745 1930 0 1930 0 0 432 0 432 -45 -72 c-85 -138 -151 -202 -209 -202 -65 0 -85 40 -87 175 -2 140 -18 161 -77 97 -46 -50 -153 -224 -155 -252 -1 -18 -7 -20 -37 -18 l-35 3 2 80 c2 44 5 91 9 105 5 24 5 23 -17 -5 -44 -60 -135 -147 -171 -166 -49 -25 -112 -25 -138 1 -29 29 -33 61 -17 138 l14 70 -60 -44 c-32 -24 -63 -44 -68 -44 -5 0 -6 -19 -3 -42 11 -86 -57 -158 -148 -158 -39 0 -54 5 -73 25 -14 13 -25 31 -25 39 0 24 48 74 100 103 l48 27 -31 57 -31 56 -54 -44 c-30 -25 -65 -50 -78 -55 -20 -10 -23 -16 -18 -52 10 -84 -58 -156 -148 -156 -39 0 -54 5 -73 25 -14 13 -25 31 -25 39 0 24 48 74 100 103 l49 27 -26 46 -26 46 -81 -81 c-99 -100 -170 -138 -266 -143 -55 -3 -70 0 -100 20 -96 65 -67 247 51 325 33 22 56 28 110 31 63 4 70 2 95 -23 22 -22 25 -32 21 -62 -11 -64 -79 -113 -184 -134 -70 -13 -79 -28 -44 -70 16 -20 28 -24 68 -23 67 1 142 43 229 129 59 59 72 78 78 114 7 48 52 101 84 101 27 0 55 -34 48 -58 -4 -10 -17 -29 -31 -42 l-24 -23 32 -58 c18 -32 34 -59 37 -59 3 0 36 23 73 51 55 40 73 61 92 104 35 79 83 106 119 66 21 -23 15 -49 -19 -81 l-25 -23 32 -56 c17 -31 33 -58 34 -60 2 -2 33 18 69 43 67 48 101 88 91 104 -7 11 60 26 74 17 15 -9 12 -70 -7 -163 -16 -75 -16 -83 -1 -98 21 -21 45 -13 106 35 64 51 160 179 158 211 -1 18 6 27 25 34 15 5 35 6 44 2 16 -6 17 -16 11 -99 l-7 -92 49 75 c65 101 114 142 166 138 62 -5 77 -33 83 -164 5 -106 14 -144 33 -144 20 0 78 62 130 139 47 69 58 80 78 76 l22 -5 0 310 0 310 -1930 0 -1930 0 0 -745z m499 358 c-30 -38 -44 -42 -145 -43 l-101 0 -12 -62 c-7 -35 -15 -74 -18 -87 l-6 -24 79 6 c44 3 88 9 97 13 23 8 21 -8 -4 -40 -19 -24 -26 -26 -99 -26 l-79 0 -12 -57 c-20 -98 -18 -115 16 -132 24 -12 42 -12 100 -3 38 6 80 14 93 18 13 4 22 2 22 -4 0 -6 -10 -22 -22 -36 -26 -29 -94 -46 -189 -46 -122 0 -138 23 -111 163 l19 98 -23 -5 c-12 -3 -30 -9 -40 -13 -17 -6 -16 -4 2 28 13 22 29 35 46 37 23 3 27 10 38 65 6 34 14 73 17 86 5 22 4 23 -28 16 -19 -4 -47 -14 -62 -22 -16 -8 -31 -12 -34 -10 -6 7 24 64 39 74 7 4 90 11 183 14 94 3 187 6 209 7 35 2 37 1 25 -15z m2587 -21 c-18 -34 -91 -92 -117 -92 -40 0 -31 56 10 65 15 3 47 19 71 35 24 16 46 28 48 26 2 -2 -3 -18 -12 -34z m-2037 -47 c25 3 57 9 70 12 23 6 24 5 17 -42 -4 -26 -10 -54 -13 -62 -4 -10 6 -8 36 8 51 26 129 23 162 -7 98 -87 40 -283 -101 -342 -22 -9 -57 -13 -101 -10 l-67 4 -17 -84 c-9 -46 -15 -98 -13 -115 3 -31 2 -32 -37 -32 -39 0 -40 1 -43 35 -2 20 11 100 28 179 16 79 30 147 30 150 0 3 -14 -11 -31 -32 -86 -104 -211 -116 -282 -26 l-24 31 -25 -44 c-14 -23 -31 -61 -39 -83 -7 -22 -17 -44 -21 -49 -11 -14 -48 24 -48 49 0 23 67 132 95 155 13 10 12 17 -4 48 -10 21 -27 63 -37 96 l-18 58 23 19 c34 27 61 25 61 -6 0 -31 39 -135 50 -135 15 0 61 67 75 107 10 30 19 39 40 41 63 8 50 -45 -35 -141 -28 -30 -50 -59 -50 -64 0 -5 10 -19 23 -30 60 -55 102 -53 172 9 60 53 100 113 109 163 4 22 9 48 12 58 4 14 -1 17 -35 17 -37 0 -71 19 -71 40 0 5 -3 15 -6 24 -5 13 0 13 32 5 20 -6 58 -8 83 -4z m769 -95 c2 -17 -6 -34 -22 -49 -25 -23 -27 -24 -45 -7 -18 16 -21 16 -50 1 -44 -22 -115 -116 -162 -212 -37 -76 -43 -83 -70 -83 -18 0 -32 6 -36 16 -3 8 4 65 17 126 12 61 22 132 23 157 1 25 6 49 12 53 17 13 65 9 71 -6 3 -8 -1 -50 -9 -93 -8 -43 -14 -79 -12 -81 1 -2 13 14 26 35 31 50 106 131 144 155 19 12 44 17 70 16 34 -3 40 -6 43 -28z" />
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M1163 894 c-48 -24 -59 -42 -77 -134 -21 -112 -22 -109 20 -126 88 -37 184 44 184 156 0 52 -24 98 -56 110 -32 13 -33 13 -71 -6z" />
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M1995 930 c-32 -13 -75 -65 -90 -106 -7 -22 -10 -40 -5 -42 22 -8 93 22 125 52 60 57 39 125 -30 96z" />
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M2329 656 c-41 -28 -53 -48 -36 -65 28 -28 86 5 90 53 3 38 -11 41 -54 12z" />
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M2639 656 c-41 -28 -53 -48 -36 -65 28 -28 86 5 90 53 3 38 -11 41 -54 12z" />
</group>
</vector>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this class

```
private class VectorDrawableUtils {

    Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int drawableResId) {
        return VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), drawableResId, context.getTheme());
    }

    Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int drawableResId, int colorFilter) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable(context, drawableResId);
        drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorFilter), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        return drawable;
    }

}
```

And call it like this

```
 new VectorDrawableUtils().getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.x,R.color.black);
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no way to change it in the xml file?

Comment: From this XML file, you can not. But you can try different SVG or try to change the color from Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make it so, however, you have to manually change your vector.
Currently, first `path` contains all letters and rectangle background.
To make all letter white you can use should extract letter in separate `path` and set `fillColor` for it. And so on.

BTW, why don't you use custom font for the purpose of text drawing? I think it is much more flexible and better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Change Fill color if you want to change inside color
If you want change stroke color then change it's color